# Snowflake Dynamic Table support for`UNION ALL`

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dynamic-tables

While trying to modify an existing table to be a Dynamic table, I noticed that it was not incrementally refreshing like I had hoped. `refresh_mode_reason` is given as below.

> Change tracking is not supported on queries with UNION ALLs or outer joins that would produce conflicting ROW_IDs.

However, within the table in [Understanding dynamic table refresh: Types of queries that support incremental refreshes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/dynamic-tables-refresh) it says:

> Dynamic tables support UNION ALL.

#### theories

1. Behind-the-scenes Snowflake determines whether the `UNION ALL` results in "conflicting `ROW_ID`s, if so, only full refresh is supported
2. the docs are misleading and should really say: "Dynamic tables support UNION ALL, but not incremental refresh"
3. Or is this a bug with dynamic tables?

#### related questions

[Dynamic tables with UNION -- change tracking not enabled](https://community.snowflake.com/s/question/0D5Do00000uBRzsKAG/dynamic-tables-with-union-change-tracking-not-enabled)

Comment: Could you share the UNION ALL query used as DT definition?